# How to host tensorflow model online

Tags: android, docker, github, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to serve an ML Model as REST API using TensorFlow Serving.

I want to know whether there's a way to host the model online rather than locally?

Thanks a lot in advance.

I need to host a ML model where there's a mapping going with a string id when doing predictions.

The model is a .h5 file.

The program runs in a notebook. But I don't know how to do the hosting, when developing the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to pack your model into a docker container and host it on any VPS like AWS EC2 or DigitalOcean.

There is a medium article that describes the process of creating the container. It is rather old, but should be mostly relevant even today.

[Serving ML Quickly with TensorFlow Serving and Docker](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008&sa=D&source=docs&ust=1683365386667147&usg=AOvVaw1AC2iG-9lJ5uFPXYqwfJMV)

After you have your container, you can follow any guide that describes how to publish it to the cloud.

For example:

[Deploy to AWS, Docker in 10 Minutes! | by Milan McGraw | Geek Culture | Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-to-aws-docker-in-10-minutes-68a60724dcb9)

Also, if you do not strictly need to use tf serving, you could look into some projects specifically designed to ease the deployment process like BentoML. I am confident there are plenty of guides online that describe how to host the app on any platform.

[BentoML: Build, Ship, Scale AI Applications](https://www.bentoml.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much @OlegKostromin I have already developed the tensor flow model. Then, can you please let me know whether I'd be able to continue keeping the tf to use BentoML?

Comment: Or do you mean we can't use tf in BentoML at all?

Comment: You can keep your existing tf model, but serve it with BentoML. Please have a look into the documentation section of BentoML about tensorflow. https://docs.bentoml.org/en/latest/frameworks/tensorflow.html